# Выхватить ID поста и подставить динамично в PHP код

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Имеются два SELECT поля: 
В первом селекте я вывожу заголовки всех записей и получаю их ID, мне этот ID нужно выхватить и подставить динамично в PHP код второго селекта сюда 'post__in' => array( код ID ) -- вместо константы '40'  
Сайт с полями для наглядности http://product-system.lianopic.co.il/index.php/user-page/

Код первого:

```
<?php
                    $query_args = [
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'post_type' => 'movie',
                    ];
                    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); ?>
                        <label for="search">Search by Post title</label> 
                        <select id="country_list" class="postlist-chosen required">
                            <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                                while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ?>
                                <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                                <option  name="search" id="search" value="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();?> - ID: <?php the_ID() ?></option>
                            <?php }} ?>
                        </select>
```

Код второго:

```
                            <?php   
                                $query_args = [
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'post_type' => 'movie',
                                    'post__in' => array( 40 ),
                                ];$query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); ?>
                                    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                                  while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
                                            if( have_rows('repeater_machines') ):
                                            while ( have_rows('repeater_machines') ) : the_row(); 
                                                $country = get_sub_field('country');
                                                        ?>
                                                        <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                                                        <option value="<?=$country?>"><?=$country?></option>
                                                        <?
                                                endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>           
                                                <?php }} ?>
                                            </select>
```

Comment: Задача связывания двух списков (если я правильно вас понял) не решается только php, нужен js. И тут есть два варианта: либо при изменении первого списка делать ajax запрос за элементами второго, либо запросить оба целиком, а второй фильтровать на стороне фронта. Выбор зависит от объема списков. Можно конечно на любой onchange делать субмит формы, но это плохой путь.

Comment: Я поэтому и написал сюда, так как здесь реализация на JS. 
Оба списка будут очень большими, где-то до 950 элементов внутри

Comment: Тогда на изменение первого списка должен висеть js скрипт, который посылает ajax запрос на сервер и передает выбранный id. А ответ на этот запрос пишет во второй список. При этом на сервере должен быть отдельный url (страница) который отвечает на этот запрос. Ответом может быть уже сформированный html состоящий из списка option, что чуть проще или json.

Comment: Вопрос первый, как это все написать.. И второй, не будет оно слишком долго передавать данные ?
Я делаю поиск, использую тоже AJAX, тестирую его на 3-4 постах - ищет бодро.
Но боюсь, что когда у меня будет 1000 записей, поиск будет занимать целые минуты... или я ошибаюсь ?

Answer (score 1):

Если абстрагироваться от вашей конкретики, то упрощенно с jquery можно так:

```php
<?php
$query_args = [...];
$list1 = new WP_Query( $query_args ); 
?>

<select id="list1">
    <option val=""></option>
    <?php foreach ($list1 as $item): ?>
        <option value="<?=$item->id?>"><?=$item->title?></option>
    <?php endforeach?>
</select>

<select id="list2">
    <option val=""></option>
</select>

<script>
    $("#list1").on("change", function(){
        $("#list2").load("/list2.php?id=" + $(this).val()); //ссылка на вторую страницу с get параметром
    });
</script>
```

И отдельная страница у вас должна быть (в примере list2.php), которая отдает вот это:

```php
<?php
$query_args = [
    ...
    id => $_GET["id"]
];
$list2 = new WP_Query( $query_args );
?>
<option val=""></option>
<?php foreach ($list2 as $item): ?>
    <option value="<?=$item->id?>"><?=$item->title?></option>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Разумеется надо проверять `$_GET` перед запросом к БД и размещать вторую страницу в соответствии с тем, как у вас настроены url в wordpress или ином движке.

Comment: Если пишете ответ, то надо давать рабочий код. Ваш выдаст 500.

Comment: @KAGGDesign в ответах с php крайне сложно дать воспроизводимый пример в отрыве от целевой платформы. Это именно пример, а не решение, чтобы автор понял, в каком направлении ему двигаться. Если вы видите просто опечатку — исправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Это вопрос с меткой WordPress. Здесь ajax так не работает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign дайте свой ответ с описанием, как правильно и корректно делать ajax хук на стороне wordpress или дополните мой 